# ngClick not working on ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-click

I have an iterating table of items. Right now, when you click an item, nothing is happening. After some testing, I see the ngClick directive is not firing. For what its worth, all my other Angular on the page is working just fine (same controller).

**HTML:**

```
<form name="areaForm" ng-submit="createArea(areaData)">
    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Area Name" ng-model="areaData.name" required/><br />

      <!-- Group search -->
      <label>Department</label>
      <input name="group" id="group-search-box" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Begin typing a department..." ng-focus="focus = true" required>

      <!-- Group filter results -->
      <table ng-show="focus">
        <tr class="group-search-result" ng-repeat="group in groups | filter : groupSelect" id="{{ group.id }}">
          <td ng-click="setSelectedGroup(group.id)">{{ group.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>

  </form>
```

**Angular.js**

```
$scope.setSelectedGroup = function(group){
  console.log(group);
  getElementById('#group-search-box').setAttribute('value', group.name);
};

$scope.selectGroup = function(group){
  var thisGroup = $filter('filter')($scope.groups, {id: group})[0];
};
```

Comment: add your `ng-click` on <tr> element.

Comment: I had tried that as well, still nothing firing.

Comment: your code is fine and working as well check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cdDGwCjehMbyWFYy1xBB?p=preview). Any error in console ?

Comment: No errors in console. Nothing appearing out of the norm. To track my issue, I changed code to ng-click="alert('triggered')" and still had no alert pop up. If I change to onclick instead, the alert fired.

Comment: the plunkr gaurvav linked worked for me too .. also worked for me when placing alert("the id you passed the controller is :" + group)  after the console.log(group) line . that would say the group id not the object or the person's name of course.  I'm using chrome.  Could it be that you're trying to do something else with the id? ... that id wouldn't help you find an element within your array of objects without some search or something. If you wanted an alert with the person's name you'd be better off with "setSelectedGroup(group)" Not "selectedGroup(group.id)" ?